# Fractional powers integral formula

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

I found this formula for the case of operators in H.O.Fattorini's book [Second Order Linear Differential Equations in Banach Spaces.](https://www.elsevier.com/books/second-order-linear-differential-equations-in-banach-spaces/fattorini/978-0-444-87698-0) page 51.$$(-a)^\alpha=\frac{\sin(\alpha \pi)}{\pi} \int_0^\infty \frac{x^{\alpha-1}}{x-a} (-a) \,dx.$$
Can anyone give me an idea from where this formula came in the scalar case.

Comment: There are several proofs in the answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/110457/695196).

Comment: @RobertLee thanks! that is very helpful.

Comment: @FrankW yes it does, thanks